# PHP: How do I populate a member of my object with a string?

Tags: php, object, xpath, member, private-members

I've got a problem with offsets because when there's no title, rather than having `<cd title="No Title">`, I have `<cd>`, in my xml file.

When there is no title attribute, I want to add the string "No Title" to the `title` member of my `cd` object.

Please look at the following code:

```
//SEEMS TO WORK
foreach ($Steps as $step){
  $cd->SetCD($cdkey->nodeValue);
  $titleQuery = './@title';
  $nullTitle = "No Title Listed";
  $areTitles  = $xpath->query($titleQuery, $step);
  //DOES NOT WORK
  if (!$areTitles)
  {
    $entry->SetTitles($title->$nullTitle)
  }
  //END DOES NOT WORK
  //WORKS
  else{
    $entry->SetTitles($title->$titleQuery) 
  }
}
```

How can I change the lines between `//DOES NOT WORK` and `//END DOES NOT WORK`, or the rest of the code, such that I get the desired result:

```
 [title:Entry:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => no title
                    [1] => no title
                    [2] => Bounce
                    [3] => Bound
                    [4] => Bounty
                )
```

instead of:

```
 [title:Entry:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Bounce
                    [1] => Bound
                    [2] => Bounty
                )
```

?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DOMXPath::query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) returns a [`DOMNodeList`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) so your statement

```
if (!$areTitles)
```

will never evaluate to true.

Instead, try

```
if (0 == $areTitles->length)
```

Comment: This worked.  It made the output values null.  It's handled, so this isn't vital, but is there a way to populate them with a string, instead?

Comment: The correct block is basically checking to see if the array is empty, right?

Comment: Got it, Phil  I changed `$title->$mystring` to `$mystring`